# Como analisar sinalizações na página de moderação?

Tags: suporte, sinalização

Pela primeira vez tenho reputação para acessar as ferramentas de moderador :D, e já me surgiram algumas dúvidas.

[Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12630/3117), tem uma sinalização dizendo que ela não é uma resposta, entretanto a data da sinalização é de quando a resposta era apenas um link, inclusive eu mesmo adicionei um comentário (ou será que eu sinalizei?) dizendo que o autor da resposta deveria incluir o texto do link em sua resposta, logo, quando o autor alterou a resposta ela passou a fazer sentido e eu inclusive dei meu voto a favor, alguns dias atrás.

1ª pergunta: quando eu clico em recomendar exclusão na lista de baixa qualidade eu estou sinalizando? Pois não aparece nada no meu flag-summary, portanto acredito que não é uma sinalização, apenas uma recomendação, estou correto?

2ª pergunta: independente de quem sinalizou a resposta, que ação devo tomar? Levando em conta que no momento que a resposta foi sinalizada ela realmente não era uma boa resposta para os modelos do SO, entretanto depois que o autor da resposta a melhorou a sinalização me parece inválida.

3ª e última pergunta: esse texto aparece na página de sinalização: `considerada inválida por 3 usuários`. O que está sendo considerado inválido de acordo com o texto? Outros 3 usuários com acesso as ferramentas de moderação consideraram a sinalização inválida?

Comment: Apagaram alguns comentários na resposta que eu linkei e a sinalização sumiu da fila. Espero que entendam minha dúvida mesmo com algumas informações terem sido modificadas desde que eu fiz a pergunta aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Esta pergunta e resposta estão obsoletas, já que a "fila de flags de 10k" (como é conhecida a página em questão) [foi removida do sistema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). Seu conteúdo foi movido para a fila de análise de posts de baixa qualidade, de maneira a desafogar o trabalho dos moderadores e o volume de informações apresentadas a eles em outra ferramenta parecida.**

> 1ª pergunta: quando eu clico em recomendar exclusão na lista de baixa qualidade eu estou sinalizando? Pois não aparece nada no meu flag-summary, portanto acredito que não é uma sinalização, apenas uma recomendação, estou correto?

Na verdade funciona como um voto. 6 votos de recomendar exclusão/excluir causam a exclusão efetiva do post (ou somente 3 votos para excluir, disponível aos usuários confiáveis).

> 2ª pergunta: independente de quem sinalizou a resposta, que ação devo tomar? Levando em conta que no momento que a resposta foi sinalizada ela realmente não era uma boa resposta para os modelos do SO, entretanto depois que o autor da resposta a melhorou a sinalização me parece inválida.

Sim, a ação correta é marcar a sinalização como inválida. Os moderadores saberão lidar com os flags conflitantes da maneira adequada. Em geral, o resultado é que todos os sinalizadores no post terminem marcados como "disputados", embora possa haver outras situações dependendo da ação do moderador.

> 3ª e última pergunta: esse texto aparece na página de sinalização: `considerada inválida por 3 usuários`. O que está sendo considerado inválido de acordo com o texto? Outros 3 usuários com acesso as ferramentas de moderação consideraram a sinalização inválida?

Exatamente, outros 3 usuários com acesso às ferramentas de moderação consideraram a sinalização inválida.

Comment: Não sabia que essa tela era temporária. Achei ela meio confusa na verdade, enfim, valeu pela resposta.

Comment: Não é exatamente "temporária", ela já existe há muitos anos e agora desistiram dela.